# submision of disabled element in form

Tags: html, forms, submit

how can I submit disabled inputs in a form?

Comment: fyi: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.12.1

Answer (score 5):

You can't (at least no in anything approaching a sensible way). "disabled" means "do not submit this control"

Perhaps you mean "readonly" instead?

Comment: ok,i should use readonly and assign a css class that presents disable effect.yeah?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.12

By default you can't do this.  You could store the value in a hidden input or something if you want to pass it with your form submission.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you could submit a disabled input is use javascript to create a hidden input when something is switched to disabled and remove it when enabled.

Answer (score 0):

If you feel like doing some JavaScript, you could have it enable your form elements when the user clicks submit.

document.getElementById("my-form-element").disabled=false

Comment: This will still keep them from being sent, since onsubmit is executed BEFORE the event ist actually processed. I guess this would be possible with setTimeout, but readonly is definitely the cleaner approach.